# Consuming TIFF tiles from MapProxy with geotiff.js

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapserver, mapproxy

I have a [MapServer](https://mapserver.org/) WMS set up from which I request GeoTIFF tiles to process in the browser using the [geotiff-js](https://geotiffjs.github.io/) library. I want to add [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) as an intermediate layer to improve performance by caching tiles. While using the MapSever WMS directly with geotiff-js works without a problem, I can't get it to work with MapProxy. Ideally, I would like MapProxy to serve the same TIFF tiles it reads from MapServer, but it seems MapProxy applies some sort of transformation and the tiles lose the georeferences.

Here is the relevant part of my `mapproxy.yaml` configuration:

```
layers:
  - name: layer1
    title: layer1
    sources: [layer1_cache]

caches:
  layer1_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [layer1]
    format: image/GeoTIFF
    request_format: image/GeoTIFF

sources:
  layer1:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: https://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/mapserv?
      map: /ms/wmstryout.map
      layers: layer1
      transparent: true
      version: 1.3.0
    supported_srs: ['EPSG:3857']
```

And here is my JavaScript, comments added with debug info:

```js
async function showMap () {

    let mapserverUrl = "https://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/ms/wmstryout.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/tiff&TRANSPARENT=true&RULE=Rule256&LAYERS=layer1&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&time=1601902785456&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=1958010.9165530764,6090502.413762843,1959233.9090056391,6091725.406215406";

    let mapproxyUrl = "http://localhost:8080/service?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/GeoTIFF&TRANSPARENT=true&RULE=Rule256&LAYERS=layer1&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&time=1601902785456&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=1958010.9165530764,6090502.413762843,1959233.9090056391,6091725.406215406";
      
    // const response = await fetch(mapserverUrl);
    const response = await fetch(mapproxyUrl);
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const tiff = await GeoTIFF.fromArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer);

    const image = await tiff.getImage(); // MapServer: image.geoKeys has value, MapProxy: image.geoKeys is null

    const width = image.getWidth(); // MapSever: 256, MapProxy: 256
    const height = image.getHeight(); // MapSever: 256, MapProxy: 256
    const tileWidth = image.getTileWidth(); // MapSever: 256, MapProxy: 256
    const tileHeight = image.getTileHeight(); // MapSever: 8, MapProxy: 256
    const samplesPerPixel = image.getSamplesPerPixel(); // MapSever: 1, MapProxy: undefined

    // when we are actually dealing with geo-data the following methods return
    // meaningful results:
    const origin = image.getOrigin(); // MapServer: some values, MapProxy: Uncaught (in promise) Error: The image does not have an affine transformation. getOrigin geotiffimage.js:680
    const resolution = image.getResolution(); // MapServer: some values, MapProxy: Uncaught (in promise) Error: The image does not have an affine transformation. getResolution geotiffimage.js:719
    const bbox = image.getBoundingBox(); // MapServer: some values, MapProxy: Uncaught (in promise) Error: The image does not have an affine transformation. getOrigin geotiffimage.js:680

    const data = await image.readRasters(); // MapServer: array of length 1, containing a Float32Array with raster data, MapProxy: array of length 0

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const plot = new plotty.plot({
        canvas,
        data: data[0],
        width: image.getWidth(),
        height: image.getHeight(),
        domain: [0, 1],
        colorScale: "summer"
    });
    plot.render();
}

showMap();
```

I also tried to open the URLs in QGIS and got the following:
[image]
`Layer has no coordinate reference system set! This layer is not georeferenced and has no geographic information available.`
QGIS is able to render both tiles correctly (i.e. they are the same visually), but notice the change in the min/max values.

I run MapProxy version 1.12.0, which according to official documentation, should georeference all GeoTIFF WMS responses (see https://mapproxy.org/blog/new-mapproxy-1.12.0-release/)

Comment: Please don't abuse the WMS protocol - if you want georeferenced GeoTiff of your data use the WCS protocol which is designed for this